# LAN drivers causing Layer 4 corruption

Tags: networking, linux-mint, drivers, ssl

I'm relatively sure that my drivers are causing some level 4 packet corruption on my system. I'd like to know how to solve this..

Diagnostics:

- any form of `git clone` on large repos will invariably give me a `RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-24): Decryption has failed` error.
- Doing a `apt-get upgrade` with large packages will cause a `bad mac` failure.
- Websites will sometimes not load assets, at random. This includes anything from css to images.
- Attempting to `curl` a file bigger than a few MB will cause `OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000119:SSL routines::decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0`.
- The above does not happen with ping or traceroute, who both work fine with default settings, using layer 3 as their transport.
- The above does not happen when I boot into windows, or use my USB wifi dongle with my PC.

And so I'm convinced now there there are either driver bugs or corruption somewhere on my system. I'm not sure entirely how to debug this on my own. What can I do to further diagnose and possibly solve this issue?

I'm including the configuration here:

kernel version:

```
$ uname -r 
5.15.0-78-generic
```

pci id:

```
$ lspci -nn 
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
```

interface drivers & firmware:

```
$ sudo ethtool -i eno1
driver: r8125
version: 9.011.01-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

interface config:

```
$ ethtool -k eno1
Features for eno1:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
    tx-checksum-ipv4: on
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ipv6: on
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: off
    tx-scatter-gather: off
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
    tx-tcp-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off
generic-segmentation-offload: off [requested on]
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: off [fixed]
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]
tx-tunnel-remcsum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-list: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
rx-gro-list: off
macsec-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp-gro-forwarding: off
hsr-tag-ins-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-tag-rm-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-dup-offload: off [fixed]
```

#### Edit:

after reviewing the steps suggested and turning off Generic Segmentation/Receive Offload, I'm still getting the following error when `wget`-ing large files

`Read error at byte 128106483/6140975104 (error:0A000119:SSL routines::decryption failed or bad record mac). Retrying.`

Comment: First, identify the kernel version (`uname -r`) and the network driver used (`ethtool -i <name of your network interface>`). Also the firmware version of the network interface, if applicable (also reported by `ethtool -i`). Try pinging with larger packets, e.g. `ping -M do -s 1472 hostname.example`; adjust the size number as needed to find the largest size that works.

Comment: @telcoM ping is layer 3. I can do very large ( 100k < ) packets very reliably. Layer 4 is the issue. Any tcp and udp transfers are subject to this corruption..

Comment: The fact that you've tested ping *with large packets* is good information. So which TCP/UDP/IP offload features does your NIC have (`ethtool -k`)? Does the corruption go away if you disable them? Is the driver very new or the NIC hardware model known for hardware bugs or other trickiness? Since much of layer-4 functionality is also shared with your WiFi dongle that you said works fine, it seems it must be something specific to that particular NIC and/or its driver. (Please *edit your question* to add any extra information.)

Comment: @telcoM I should say- that my USB wifi dongle is working fine, the *integrated wifi* is not.

Comment: "ping is layer 3"....why do people keep tryng to describe IP in terms of the OSI model?

Comment: @symcbean Because that's how theory of networking is often taught to them. Unfortunately many courses gloss over the fact that a "pure" OSI model networking stack would be inefficient in practice, and real implementations tend to couple together or outright merge some layers to e.g. allow for hardware acceleration of some features that belong "higher" in the OSI stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a Realtek RTL8125, and it's an out-of-kernel driver. Did you download it yourself, or did your distribution's automation load it for you?

The driver version 9.011.01-NAPI suggests it might be [the latest version of the driver released by Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software). Apparently the version number can have various suffixes (`-NAPI`, `-REALWOW`, `-PTP`, `-RSS` and either `-PRINTER` or `-DASH`) according to the build-time options selected.

There also seems to be [numerous forks off the Realtek-released driver on Github.](https://github.com/search?q=r8125&type=repositories)

This line in your `ethtool -k` output looks a bit suspicious:

```
generic-segmentation-offload: off [requested on]
```

So your network driver *claimed* to implement the Generic Segmentation Offload feature, but then apparently could not hold its end of the bargain and failed to enable it when requested to. That definitely makes me think there might be something wrong in the network interface's hardware or the driver that is attempting to use it.

You might try disabling it and the Generic Receive Offload feature as it is the receive-side complement of the Generic Segmentation Offload:

```
sudo ethtool -K eno1 generic-segmentation-offload off generic-receive-offload off
```

I also found that [the OpenWrt project's version of this driver](https://github.com/csrutil/realtek-r8125-openwrt/blob/main/README.md) might also have had some trouble with the Receive-Side Scaling (RSS) feature of this network interface chip, as they note in their `README.md` file:

> The latest version of the driver has the RSS feature disabled by default, even if the compilation option is enabled, it will not take effect.

Since your driver version does not show the `-RSS` suffix, it might have not been built in, and so might not be relevant to your situation, though.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with that NIC or the drivers provided by Realtek. But now at least your question has plenty of useful information so someone else with the right knowledge might have easier time finding the question and answering to it.

Comment: ah, my bad, I didn't notice the -i flag in one comment and the -k flag in the other comment

Comment: updated OP with the `ethtool -i` output